# How to access email using facebook android sdk 3.0.1

Tags: java, android, facebook, sdk

i have searched alot but not getting how to access email using facebook android sdk 3.0.1
i have already given the permission.

can anybody tell me in detail.
Thnx in advance

Comment: you mean facebook messages?

Comment: I got the answer of my question after setting the permission of email i am able to fetch email id from facebook